# Unable to pass struct array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Learning C and need to populate array of five struct elements but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the struct array to a function and I keep getting error:

```
error: conflicting types for 'dealFiveHand'
```

Here is the code:

```
#define HAND_SIZE 5

void dealFiveHand(struct Card *wHand[]);

struct Card {
    char suit;
    char face;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Card *hand[HAND_SIZE];
    dealFiveHand(hand); 
}

void dealFiveHand(struct Card *wHand[])
{
   ...
}
```

Do I need to define and initialize a pointer and then pass that pointer to the function?

Comment: Is that the complete error message? There's nothing else? No informational notes or anything else printed as part of the error?

Comment: Please show the *full* error message. Please show the *exact* code as a [mcve] (what you have is close already so just make it the actual code with the actual error message including line numbers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least you need to move the definition of `struct Card` BEFORE function `dealFiveHand` prototype - that way the function knows about the type of its parameter.

```
struct Card {
    char suit;
    char face;
};

void dealFiveHand(struct Card *wHand[]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Not sure how I was missing it.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring Card, before defining it. Declare it first, before referring it, as a argument of your function `dealFiveHand()`